# Query MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, mamp

I am trying to query a MySQL database with PHP and return the results as JSON. I'm new to PHP and web development so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've set up the database using MAMP. My parameters are being printed but I'm not getting the JSON. I've gotten this far with the help of a tutorial.

EDIT: I just went into phpMyAdmin to make sure it was working and when I click on Server:localhost:8889, a window pops up that says Error in processing request. Error code 404.

I'm thinking this is the problem, I'm just not sure why it isn't working. I may reinstall MAMP.

```
    <?php

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'TestDB';
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '8889';

$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'first_name');
$last_name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'last_name');
$membership_number = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'membership_number');

echo $first_name;
echo $last_name;
echo $membership_number;

// Create connection
    // $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "TestDB");
    // $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "TestDB", "8889", $socket);
    $link = mysqli_init();
    $con = mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $user, $password, $db, $port);

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE FIRST_NAME = \'$first_name\' and LAST_NAME = \'$last_name\' and MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER = \'$membership_number\'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if(!$result) {
        die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    // Check for results
    // if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    if($result) {
        // If there are results, create results array and a temporary one to hold the data
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        // Loop through each row in the result set
        // while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            // Add each row to the results array
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        echo $tempArray;
        echo $resultArray;
        echo $result;

        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }

    // Close connections
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an array of results back into $resultArray?

Comment: It sounds as if your `if` condition never occurs. Are you getting back a result? You're no error checking your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change you `$sql` variable to remove the escapes on the single quotes.  They register as part of the string because you are using double-quotes to wrap it.  Basically, you're telling the database to run the query "`SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE FIRST_NAME = \'John\' and LAST_NAME = \'Smith\' and MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER = \'VRX78435\'`".  This will error if you run it directly because the escape characters are not escaping.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE FIRST_NAME = '$first_name' and LAST_NAME = '$last_name' and MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER = '$membership_number'";
```

That should fix it for you.

There may also be an issue with your connection to the server.  `mysqli_query()` uses the results of `mysqli_connect()` to run the query.  `mysqli_real_connect()` only returns a boolean value, so it is invalid for this particular use (at least it failed to work on my server).

This would be a simple matter of replacing the `$con` and then you can drop the `$link` variable.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db, $port);
```

These changes, and assuming the `$first_name`, `$last_name`, and `$membership_number` are all valid, allowed your script to run for me, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! The quotes along with the mysqli_connect idea worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  Just as a heads up, though mysqli is the standard, I highly recommend you switch to using the PDO format.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are using procedural style coding

Instead of

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
```

You need `mysqli_fetch_object` in procedural style

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
```

Comment: No, it sure isn't. I am not getting a result. How can I print the error in if(!$result){}?

Comment: instead of mysqli_real_connect try with $con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

Comment: I still don't get anything.

Comment: can u var_dump($row) inside your while loop, is any result showing?

Comment: have you changed the connection arguments, to ur parameters in mysqli_connect?

Comment: Your suggestion to use mysql_connect worked. I forgot to remove the link variable.